# Azure Recovery Services, how to view protected items associated with DPM

Tags: azure, dpm

Is it possible to view list of protected items (hyper-v machines and sql db basically) associated with Data Protection Manager 2012 R2?
Using Service Protection dashboard im able to see overall usage, but the list is not specified.
also would be interesting to find the way to manage (restore) protected items using PowerShell cmdlets
Thank you for helping,

Answer (score 1):

I've asked Microsoft this question and they have indicated that there isn't a way to access the protected items on the portal at this time.  They are supposed to be working on it but I haven't heard anything about it lately.

Rob